# App size increases in Google Play Store before download

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have built a 4MB sized app for the Google Play Store (only available for Sri Lanka unfortunately) and I have been reported recently that some users cannot download the app because the app can be too large, sometimes reaching a size of 40 to 400MB.

I tried to find what may be causing this problem, but I cannot replicate this scenario on my device. What are the factors that can cause this type of bloating of the app size, and what can I do to reduce this?

I have used firebase analytics and crash reporting services and in an earlier question, I was told it might contribute to this. Is this true, and how?

Edit:- Here is the top level build.gradle source

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is app level build file:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "observerjobs.com.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 6
        versionName "0.2.2"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.14.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.+'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: How is it possible app size increased to 400MB??

Comment: OMG !! 400 MB ??

Comment: check ,you used to take data from service and stored into app continuously.can you share your app's playstore url?

Comment: That's why I said, "I have been reported". The only thing I know is that in some devices, the app size has been reported to increase, sometimes not being able to install the app even if a substantial amount of data has been removed.

Comment: add `shrinkResources true` in `build.gradle`

Comment: Could you share your build.gradle file source code ?

Comment: @PrateekBhardwaj is this the one you want?

Comment: send me app level build.gradle file

Comment: I have the app level one now @PrateekBhardwaj